# Bake to keyframes messes up cell fracture

Tags: keyframes, windows, glass

I am making a short animation of a sphere breaking a window with cell fracture.

Here is how it looks mid-break:

[image]

I thought it looked good so I decided to bake it into keyframes to upload it to the sheepit renderfarm. I selected them in the outliner with box select and then right clicked > select. Then I clicked bake to keyframes in the rigid body tools.

[image]

When I bake it, the sphere bakes fine, but the cell fracture pieces end up all squished looking like this:

[image]

Anyone know why this is happening? Is there a solution to this problem?

**Additional info:**

The cell fracture pieces all share the same animation data. I animated the 'Dynamic' property in order to delay the animation until needed.

To clarify, I selected all cell fractured objects at the same time.